# SIMATIC ET200 + Windows CE

Tags: windows, windows-ce, plc

I have never worked with Siemens' [SIMATIC industrial automation system](http://www.automation.siemens.com/mcms/automation/en/automation-systems/industrial-automation/Pages/Default.aspx), but I need to do following:

We have an industrial computer with Windows CE (for example an x86 Siemens TP700 comfort).

Is there a way to create a .NET application that would be able to work with SIMATIC ET200?

Or do I always need "SIMATIC NET" or Step7? I was told that SIMATIC NET does not work on Windows CE. Or can I use some OPC server that does not require SIMATIC NET?

Or is it impossible to use SIMATIC modules under Windows CE? It could be conclusion as well.

Comment: Have you checked with your Siemens rep?  I think that for something this specialized, they would be the best place to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to lauch \Windows\cgacutil.exe on your CE platform. If it is there, it will tell you the version of the '.Net compact' framework. If there is one installed, you can write applications targeting that particular version. The '.Net compact' is only a subset of the full .Net on desktops.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, first of all which ET200 fieldbus device want to work with?

Generally you must have ET200 with ethernet (ProFiNet - process field network) interface, than at least you don't have an IM151-7 (or 151-8) that are a CPU as first unit in ET200 rack you need other software to make you pc as a master profinet device, the slave device are basically stupid devices as long as initialized by a master device, that usually is the CPU.

Second thing: the TP700 is a WinCE Panel,with basic function that need to programmed into HMI software designer (WinCC for TIA Portal) and has a very limited resources.

My point of view: first you need to explain what need to do: a S7-1200 CPU even the most basic model do everything you want: address the ET200 rack, read and write the I/O data and collect them ready to be read or write from TP700: you need half day for all job, most time is need to do the graphic interface.

The other solution could be put a linux CPU (raspberry or everything else) that the necessary tasks to address ET200, read and write data to it, process the data and place them readable from TP700 (programmed with WinCC)

I'm programming automation devices from 27 years (I'm 46 year old) and I've basic knowledge of pc programming: from my point of view you get best result, reusable code, less time, less heachache with a plc cpu instead of pc code.